# logging in to umbraco 6.1 backend doesn't work anymore, keep getting errors and redirect back to login.aspx page

Tags: cookies, umbraco, p3p

after nog using the backend of our umbraco website for a few months I started developing for our website again. As the website was being used by some people, I decided to use a staging environment.
So I moved all my files and finally got the database also cloned.

But now whenever I try to login to the backend of umbraco (in the live and the staging environment) I get a javascript error in my firebug console:

```
{"Message":"The user has no umbraco contextid - try logging in","StackTrace":"   at Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.ValidateCurrentUser(HttpContextBase httpContext, Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.AuthorizeRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.WebServices.UmbracoAuthorizedWebService.AuthorizeRequest(Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.WebServices.UmbracoAuthorizedWebService.AuthorizeRequest(String app, Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at umbraco.presentation.webservices.TreeClientService.GetInitAppTreeData(String app, String treeType, Boolean showContextMenu, Boolean isDialog, TreeDialogModes dialogMode, String functionToCall, String nodeKey)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

As suggested in other posts, I delete my cookies and try again, but no luck.

I also get some other errors from time to time:

> uiKeys is undefined

I uploaded my umbraco/config/lang folder using Binary, but I still get the error sometimes

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I added this to my web.config

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false" validateRequest="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never" />
```

and the error seems gone

I also got some error about synthax in the document type declaration at the start of the logout page which I get redirected to

I have been at this for several hours and can't seem to fix it.

Locally loggin in works.

---

**Edit**

I just did a fresh install of 6.1.6 and 6.1.5 and tried to logon but I still get the error:
http://staging.mydomaimn.com/umbraco/webservices/TreeClientService.asmx/GetInitAppTreeData 500 Internal server error:
{"Message":"The user has no umbraco contextid - try logging in","StackTrace":"   at Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.ValidateCurrentUser(HttpContextBase httpContext, Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.AuthorizeRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.WebServices.UmbracoAuthorizedWebService.AuthorizeRequest(Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.WebServices.UmbracoAuthorizedWebService.AuthorizeRequest(String app, Boolean throwExceptions)\r\n   at umbraco.presentation.webservices.TreeClientService.GetInitAppTreeData(String app, String treeType, Boolean showContextMenu, Boolean isDialog, TreeDialogModes dialogMode, String functionToCall, String nodeKey)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

This is on a fresh install that never had logins before
Perhaps the problem is with the database setup. My host uses MSSQL 2012 and I have two databases, the first is for the live version which is called 'myloginname' and the second is for the staging which is called 'myloginname_1'.
is the _1 a problem when placing the logon in the database (which I read Umbraco does)?

---

**Edit 2**

just looked in my database and Umbraco does create a contextId in the db table 'umbracoUserLogins' but does not create the cookie which should contain the same 'UMB_UCONTEXT'

so this is probably my real problem, what could be causing this?

**Edit: some more info on this:**
When I look in Fiddler I can see this:
On the 'Raw' tab:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 Location: /umbraco/ Set-Cookie:
>   ASP.NET_SessionId=zjlqfoxq421wmnpeydcbxv1t; path=/; HttpOnly
>   Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=zjlqfoxq421wmnpeydcbxv1t; path=/;
>   HttpOnly Set-Cookie: UMB_UCONTEXT=694C3[...a lot of text...]CFDD5EDB;
>   expires=Tue, 12-Nov-2013 14:07:23 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly Date: Mon, 11
>   Nov 2013 14:07:23 GMT Content-Length: 126

The cookie tab shows:

> Response sent 1318 bytes of Cookie data:  Set-Cookie:
>   UMB_UCONTEXT=694C3[...a lot of text...]D5EDB; expires=Tue, 12-Nov-2013
>   14:07:23 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly This response did not contain a P3P
>   Header.

So we can conclude:

- the expiration time and date are correct
- there is a 302 error, but this seems to be for all cookies and the
  other two mentioned are created (I'm confused about this)
- perhaps the P3P headers are an issue?

Comment: I just realised I'm not on an server with Full trust but Medium trust rights. Perhaps it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this.
The reason why the UMB_UCONTEXT cookie wasn't created was that I fixed the error

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same
>   validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in
>   a cluster.

the wrong way. As [How To Fix the: “Validation of viewstate MAC failed” Error (ASP.NET MVC)](http://adam.kahtava.com/journal/2009/11/23/how-to-fix-the-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error-aspnet-mvc/) shows, I needed to create a random machinekey and add it to my web.config

Comment: The page your link points to points to a machine key generator which seems no longer be working. Here is a working one: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey